# How to check file exists in HDFS using python

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

```
import subprocess
def run_cmd(args_list):
    print('Running system command: {0}'.format(' '.join(args_list)))
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc.communicate()
    return proc.returncode

cmd = ['hadoop', 'fs', '-test', '-e', hdfs_file_path]
code = run_cmd(cmd)
if code:
    print 'file not exist'
```

When I give this command to see whether file exists in HDFS, it is throwing me this error:

```
RuntimeError: Error running command: hadoop fs -test -f /app/tmp/1.json. Return code: 1, Error: b''
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an api instead of calling subprocesses. It is always better to use an api for this for example [snakebite](https://github.com/spotify/snakebite) which is created by spotify. This example checks if a file exists in the given folder:

```
from snakebite.client import Client
client = Client("localhost", 8020, use_trash=False)
return "fileName" in client.ls(['hdfs_path'])
```

Comment: I can't install third party tools as to my server, installation is restricted. So I got to use subprocess only

Comment: Its a pure python implementation. So if python code runs on your machine this also runs? You can just develop the programm on your computer and than pack all libaries with pip install -t <folder> <package> to a folder an then upload it to your server.